# Training a model to identify names appearing in a sentence

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, named-entity-recognition

I have a dataset containing the names of about 238583 people. The names can contain more than one word for example:
 `Willie Enriquez , James J Johnson, D.J. Khaled`.
 My problem is to identify these names when it appears in a sentence. I am trying to create a machine learning model that can identify if the input is a name or not. My trouble is figuring the input and output of this model. Since I have a bunch of names I can train a model which can recognise a name when the input is a name, but what about the other words that are part of this sentence. The model should also be able to identify words that are not names. Assuming the sentences can have any other words in it, what would be the ideal dataset for this purpose? Does it make sense to train a model on a random bunch of words and tag it as NonNames?
(The entire sentences in which the names appear is not available. The user can type absolutely anything he/she wants)

Thankyou.

Comment: what language ??? python I think ?? please specify and how does the data actually look like ?

Comment: as in, if its a dataframe or what, any suggestion can only be made based on that

Comment: This problem is called [Named Entity Recognition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Named-entity_recognition). If you try to classify each word in the sentence on its own you'll throw out a lot of data and make your problem a lot harder than it has to be.

Comment: Yes. But I want to solve it using some classifier trained using the names I have. I tried using Stanford NER and Google NLP NER,  both misses out a majority of the names in the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The specifics of the answer may vary according to which model you are using, but the general idea is more or less the following:

You are trying to solve a classification task, precisely a binary classification task where you want to distinguish between proper names (assuming from your example) from other expressions.

The input to your model, in the most general case, are the features of the example that you want to classify: you should decide what features you think are useful to distinguish such names (e.g., number of words, contains capital letter, every word is capitalized, contains dotted letters, contains any word that you already have in your dataset, etc...). The output is the class, that is 0/1 for non-names/names.

You then train your model with positive examples from the dataset that you have and negative examples (i.e. non-names) taken from random words for non-names.

If the use can enter full sentences then you will need to do a preprocessing step where you extract all sequences of length N (word n-grams) and classify each of them individually with your previously trained model.

Comment: Thankyou. This is what I had in mind. Any suggestions as to what exactly used for training for non-names?

Comment: You can just select random words (and ngrams) from any text and I'm pretty sure it should work okay.