# Google Cloud Vision API get key of the extracted text

Tags: react-native, google-cloud-vision, google-cloud-sdk, google-cloud-automl, vision-api

I am using Google Cloud Vision API for scanning the business card using React-Native and the OCR part is working well. This is the my current archivement.

[image: The original image]
[image: Android app]

As you can see in the second image, the app is recognizing the text as well and I want to map it to key. Means I want to map "JOHN" to "First Name" and "SMITH" to "Last Name", +0 123 456 789 324 to "Phone Number".

```
'https://vision.googleapis.com/v1/images:annotate?key=' +
        'YOUR_API_KEY',
      {
        method: 'POST',
        body: JSON.stringify({
          requests: [
            {
              image: {content: this.state.image.base64},
              features: [{type: 'TEXT_DETECTION'}],
            },
          ],
        }),
      },
```

This is my current payload. What do you think should I use for labeling the text?
Please teach me as soon as possible.

Comment: If the fields are fixed - not dynamic, why don't you map them manually?

Comment: Users don't want to do it manually.

Comment: Then you would need to search for another service instead of Google Cloud Vision API.

Comment: Please check CamCard app, it is mapping automatically

Comment: That's what am I asking.

Answer (score 1):

You can google "text analysis api" and find the services suitable for your needs.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand this correctly, you are expecting from Cloud Vision API to classify detected text, e.g John Smith -> name, +0 12345678 -> phone, etc. If this is the case, I would suggest to use ML with a trained model to classify detected text. To do so, you can take a look on [Training a model to identify names appearing in a sentence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51476682/training-a-model-to-identify-names-appearing-in-a-sentence) and do the same for addresses, phone numbers, etc.